# Show VAT on event registration page

Tags: civievent, financial-accounts

I have activated "Sales tax" as per [the documentation], including adding Financial Type and Accounts ("Arrangemangsavgift inkl. moms"):

[image]

I've also set my event to use the Finacial Type to the one in the picture. But there is no sign of any "moms" (=VAT). Particularly I'd like to have my event registration page clearly state the VAT.

Update: I have a Price Set which uses the Financial Type:
[image]

And I've explicitly set the Financial Type of the event to use it too:
[image]

I don't see any summary/breakdown with VAT on the registration page, and any contribution created by a registration does not have such a breakdown either.

What is a good checklist to get VAT for event registrations to work? Or maybe, why does not ours work ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To enable Sales tax for an Event.

1. Enable **Enable Tax and Invoicing** setting in Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings
2. Create a Financial Account of type Liability, Is Tax Enabled and Tax Rate > 0.
3. Link Financial Account with Financial Type using 'Sales tax Account is'.
4. Use financial type configured for tax at #3 for event, price set, and price fields.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the priceset that is being included in this event. This priceset should have the tax enabled financial type selected in settings.

If you haven't created a priceset - create one from `Administer -> CiviEvent -> New Priceset` and set the financial type to the one that has a sales tax. Use this priceset on the Event Page.

Comment: I already had that. Updated the question with more pictures to show that.